# Laravel 5.5 - read the images stored in external folder

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, file-storage

In my Laravel 5.5 Project, I have saved the images in folder 'public/uploads' and  I can read the images too with the URL http://localhost/my_project/public/uploads/77FAk4TSvXbX.jpg. Then I attempted to store the images in 'D:/Uploads' which was successful using the configuration

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => 'D:/Uploads'
],
```

But now I am stuck at retrieving these images. I cannot read the images directly as in case I could do previously, straight though URL.

Can anyone please help me for this?

Here is the code written to upload images to D:/Uploads

```
$image  = str_random(12) . "." . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->image->storeAs('', $image);
```

Comment: Write down the error while trying get images...

Comment: I am stuck at how to retrieve the images. It would be easy if image could be retrieved straight through URL as described in question.

Comment: Write down the code you have written for uploading the image.

Comment: @engrhussainahmad -  Upadated the question. I have just used Laravel's functionality.

Comment: are you trying file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `'visibility' => 'public',` in the configuration file inside `local` array and then try following code:

```
$contents = Storage::get('path_to_file');
```

It should work.
If you still have any issue let me know.